# How to convert an excel diagram to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel, diagram

I've designed in Excel a diagram with different shapes and inside these shapes there are numbers that change when I execute a macro. 
I would like to develop this simulator to html with javascript, but I don't know how to draw this diagram (shapes, lines, etc) and put numbers inside them. 
I've thought to save the excel diagram as .jpg, insert in the html and put some textboxes over these shapes. But I don't know if it is the best solution.

Please, could you give any idea how to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: There are numerous libraries for rendering diagrams in html with javascript. Try to google for those.